# How can I get final URL of newly added node from hook_node_insert()?

Tags: path-aliases, nodes

I have installed `pathauto` and implemented hook_node_insert in my module, the problem is when I use `entity_uri` to get new node's URL I will get `node/xxx` instead of pathauto url alias.

How can I get final URL of the node, after ALL other modules had their manipulations?

```
function HOOK_node_insert($node) {
    $uri = entity_uri('node', $node);
    $uri['path']; // this should be the final path
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you also implement [hook_module_implements_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7) then you can change when your insert hook fires, like this:

```
function mymodule_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {
    if ($hook == 'node_insert') {
    // Move my_module_node_insert() to the end of the list. 
    $group = $implementations['my_module'];
    unset($implementations['my_module']);
    $implementations['my_module'] = $group;
  }
}
```

So now when your insert code executes the path alias should be available.

Comment: The advantage of this over changing module weight is that you can have different orderings per hook. So if for another hook you want to execute ahead of other modules, you can.

Comment: I tried to use `MYMODULE_module_implements_alter` but it seems its not being called at all.

Comment: You have to clear cache. It only gets called when the registry list of module hooks is built, not normally during a page request.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that pathauto module is triggering hook after your module hook interaction. To resolve this you have to give a higher **weight** to your module.

To increase weight, Refer this link: [How to update a module's weight](http://drupal.org/node/110238)

OR

[hook_module_implements_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7)

> This hook is invoked during module_implements(). A module may
>   implement this hook in order to reorder the implementing modules,
>   which are otherwise ordered by the module's system weight.

And also you have to use drupal_get_path_alias function in node insert, Following is a working code when the module weight is set higher value.

```
function MODULENAME_node_insert($node) {
    $system_path = 'node/'.$node->nid;
    $current_path = drupal_get_path_alias($system_path);
    drupal_set_message($current_path);
}
```

Comment: I changed my module weight to 10000 but still getting node/xxx off of `drupal_get_path_alias`. Is this because the new node is not inserted into table yet or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in drupal which gives you the [path_alias](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_get_path_alias/7)

For e.g.:

```
$path = node/$nid;    
$url = drupal_get_path_alias($path);    
print $url;
```

By this you will get desired drupal set path.

Comment: thnx @optimusprime